# MediaElement: Find out if file contains supported format

Tags: silverlight, sharepoint-2010, web-parts, mediaelement

So the Silverlight MediaElement has [certain supported media formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189080%28VS.95%29.aspx). I let my users upload files to a directory and have a MediaElement play these (via a [SharePoint 2010 Media WebPart](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sanjaynarang/archive/2010/05/26/media-web-part-in-sharepoint-2010-faq.aspx)).

I could check the file extensions of the uploaded files and depending on that display them in the Media WebPart. The problem is that the file extensions given are: MP3, ASF, MP4, 3GP, WMV. However when I have an AVI file containing H264 encoded material it would also work, but the file extension would not tell me that.

**Is there a way to check files for compatibility with the Silverlight MediaElement?**

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe their is but what is on the list of accepted formats.

Their is the option that you could reformat with a back end system to break the format down and re build it as an appropriate file.